# Sqlite in Android: DataBaseObjectNotClosedException

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have populated a `ListView` from an `SQLite` database in Android. When I run the app list view does not fill with data - it is empty. I am getting an exception of `DataBaseObjectNotClosedException` even if I close the `Cursor` also. Can anyone see where my mistake is?

Here is my log file:

```
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.sqlitedemo/databases/EmployeeReview.db' 
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at com.sqlitedemo.Employee_List.showList(Employee_List.java:148)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at com.sqlitedemo.Employee_List.onCreate(Employee_List.java:63)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-15 14:46:45.372: E/Database(18100):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my method in Activity class

```java
private void showList()
    {     

    ArrayList<Employee> EmployeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();  
    EmployeeList.clear();  

    String strQuery = "SELECT sum(empid) as emp_id, Staff_emp_name as emp_name, department as emp_dept, designation as emp_designation,"
                    +" (SUM(performance_rate_one+performance_rate_two+performance_rate_three+performance_rate_four+performance_rate_five)/5) as TotalPerformance"
                    +" FROM employee_details INNER JOIN performance"
                    +" ON employee_details.Emp_id = performance.empid "
                    +" GROUP BY empid "
                    +" ORDER BY TotalPerformance DESC";


    SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c1 =sqlDatabase.rawQuery(strQuery, null);


    if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) 
    {   
        if (c1.moveToFirst())

        {   
            do
            {    
                Employee EmployeeListItems = new Employee();  
                EmployeeListItems.setEmployeeId(c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_id")));
                EmployeeListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_name")));
                EmployeeListItems.setDepartment(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_dept")));
                EmployeeListItems.setDesignation(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_designation")));

                EmployeeListItems.setPerformancerate(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("TotalPerformance")));
                EmployeeList.add(EmployeeListItems);     

            } while (c1.moveToNext());   

    } 
        startManagingCursor(c1);
        sqlDatabase.close();
        c1.close();
    } 

        EmployeeList_Adapter contactListAdapter = new EmployeeList_Adapter(Employee_List.this, EmployeeList); 
        listEmployee.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);  
        contactListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

I'm getting error at the line

```java
SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c1 =sqlDatabase.rawQuery(strQuery, null);
```

Comment: where hav u opened ur db???

Comment: @Meghna : I have not opened database anywhere in this class , i have only read .

Comment: ok den first close cursor den database

Answer (score 2):

```
 sqlDatabase.close();
 c1.close();
```

It will be -

```
 c1.close();
 sqlDatabase.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a new database connection every time you try to show the list, and never closing it.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

You should only open the database connection once, when your application starts up, and re-use this connection throughout your app.

Comment: :I have close the data base c1.close();sqlDatabase.close(); .Still data is not showing in listview

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you getting the writable database to just read the data ? Change it to get read only database API call.
2. The below statements should be in finally. You should check if the database object is indeed open before closing it.

`sqlDatabase.close();`
`c1.close();`